# Functor from the locally free sheaves to the vector bundles. Is the proof correct?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

[image: proof from the J. Taylor's book]

I don't understand the construction of the fiber $F_x$. The right hand side is a (pre)sheaf whereas the left hand side is claimed to be a vector space. I would appreciate helping to make sense of it.

Comment: Isn't this fiber $\mathcal{M}_x/\mathcal{I}_x\mathcal{M}_x$ where $\mathcal{M}_x$ is the stalk of $\mathcal{M}$? Then $\mathcal{I}_x$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_x$ of germs of $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions at $x$, and the quotient has a vector space structure?

Comment: May be it is, at least makes sense.

Comment: May I ask what this text is?

Comment: @Jeremy Lindsay, unfortunately, I don't remember